# Remove the suffix in urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

Yes, I know this has been asked hundreds of times. But I just can't find a version that actually works. Currently, all the ones so far I've tried currently work in removing `.php`, but that is when the problems begin. A few pages on my site depend on `$_GET` requests, e.g `profile` So when you go to the url http://www.example.com/profile?username=System you will get a 404, while without the `?username=System` it works fine. The current code I have is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: have you got your AllowOrverride set to All? in xammp and http-conf? Also put Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI in your http.conf

Comment: This is being hosted on a remote server, so I don't know, but before I decided to change the page system, rewrite like this worked fine. But then pages were done by index.php?page=profile&username=System

Comment: You are getting a 404 error because the conditions in the rule set don't match and obviously there is no folder `http://www.example.com/profile?username=System` But, what script is supposed to get the parameters passed in the incoming URL. i.e  `username=System`, the script with the name `profile` (profile.php) or another one not in the URL, like `index.php`?

Comment: If going to the page `profile?username=System`, the parameters would be passed to `profile.php` while if going to `search?query=hi+there` the parameters would be passed to `search.php`.

Comment: Try changing the second rewrite condition to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Answer (score 2):

You need `[QSA]` (Query String Attached) at the end of your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA]
```

Comment: There is no query to **append** and therefore the flag would do nothing.

Comment: @faa In the URL `http://www.example.com/profile?username=System` there most certainly is a query to include.

Comment: @Faa was right ,there is no need for the QSA, QSA is helpful when target path and the requested path both have query strings then it combines them.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  .       [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .*   %1.php               [L]
```

Will map silently this

`http://www.example.com/ScriptName?key1=val1`

To:

`http://www.example.com/ScriptName.php?key1=val1`

Comment: Works perfectly, except for one small problem. When a page is being accessed without a query, you get a 404 error.

Comment: That's the expected behavior, hence `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  .       [NC]`, because I assumed the page `http://www.example.com/ScriptName`, for example, does not exist. However, if you still want to map that page to the script with it's name, without a query, just remove that line from the set of rules.